# fsck.ext4 is running in the background at 0% CPU. Is it done?

Tags: fsck

Is there a way to check if fsck is completed? I sent it to the background but don't know how to get it back.

I'm on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: try `jobs`. then you'll get a list of background jobs. then `fg %[fsck's job control id num]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'jobs' doesn't actually do anything that I can see. It doesn't print "command not found" so it's doing something...

Comment: then do `jobs -l`. Anyway, your `fsck` is almost definitely then not a child of the current shell and so you have no `job` control over it. You might use a debugger to try to get it to reopen its stdout as can sometimes be done w/ `reptyr` and see if its awaiting input, but if you can't figure out how and you didn't log its output somewhere then you'll probably never know.

Comment: still no dice, even with the -l flag :( thank you though